# Flag Options Missing - Is this a bug?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, low-quality-posts

This is normally what I see when flagging a post:
[image: Flagging Options]

Which then provides the following options:

[image: Not Belong Here Flag Options]

I have come across this problem before. Where I have wanted to flag a question, as not belonging here, but only have limited options.

[image: Limited flag Options]

When this happens, I use a custom flag and write in the reason, but am not happy doing so.

Is this a bug?

What is the best thing to do?

Comment: Vote to close, don't flag. The close votes is where the off-topic (including migration) options exist.

Comment: I don't have a vote to close option

Comment: You have a close link, no?

Comment: NO, that is the whole point of the question! lol please see screen shot

Comment: Right. That comes in at 3,000 rep.

Comment: Until you do gain that privilege, downvote such questions, comment and trust the community to close and delete them.

Comment: Oded, you have still missed the entire point of the question, I will add another screen shot

Comment: Do the close vote reasons not appear in the flagging system for people with less than 3k rep now then @Oded? They do for me... when I don't need them.

Comment: Hi Ben, and Oded, I have added complete screen shots, which shows the glitch and I was mindful not to accidentally flag the question I used to get the screen shots ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question in your screenshots is already closed. The flagging options on closed questions is intentionally reduced since there isn't a lot of manual action on closed questions that's frequently part of a workflow.

Since the flagging dialog is loaded when the button is clicked rather than when the page is loaded that leaves a race condition where a question can appear open but the flagging options imply that it is not because the question was closed by other users in the intervening period,

If you want to flag a question that's already closed you can always use a custom flag to explain what needs to be done.

Comment: no worries Flexo, thanks, good answer.. and thnx for the patience with  discussing the ins and outs of this question