# Why the flag option "very low quality" is missing in a question?

Tags: support, review, questions, flags, low-quality-posts

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530765/looking-some-coding-tips) and clicked to flag it. When I was choosing which flag to apply, I've realized that the flag option "very low quality" was missing.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Since it is a question with a negative score, why can't I see this flag option?

<sub>(which type of flag this question should receive is not related with my question)</sub>

Additional notes:

- The question does not have answers.
- The question is open, so it is not a race condition when the question is closed just after you click on it, like happened in this meta question: [Flag Options Missing - Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187641/flag-options-missing-is-this-a-bug)
- This related meta question did not help me too: 
  [Very Low Quality flag not shown for question at -1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111120/very-low-quality-flag-not-shown-for-question-at-1)

Comment: The question already has been downvoted, it'll be auto-deleted if it doesn't get answered. What would a VLQ flag achieve here?

Comment: In any case, please don't bother moderators about such posts. The community is handling it just fine by downvoting and closing. Posts like that are then dealt with entirely automatically. Flagging it as VLQ would not achieve anything here.

Comment: VLQ is now a mod-only flag? Since when?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, as I said in the question, the option that I choose is not been discussed here. I was not going to flag as VLQ, I just missed the option and was curious about the reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the question that you related as a duplicate is regarding flagging **answers** as VLQ and not **questions**. Also, I can see not closed questions that can be flagged as VLQ so I don't understand what Waffles said.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I also think that this must be a more recent development since unclosed questions could certainly be flagged VLQ a few months ago, when I asked: [Why can questions be flagged but not closed for very low quality?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239688/255554).

Comment: Also, Waffle’s statement was: “It is only available on closed questions **or** posts with a score less than 1” – so a question does not need to be closed to be flagged; it could also have a non-positive score.

Comment: @JanDvorak ^^^ it's not mod only, since recently VLQ is simply not available for questions under triage or close review

Comment: @Wrzlprmft see above, currently VLQ flags are not available for questions under review, [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/165773)

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, voted for a proper dupe

Comment: @JanDvorak: VLQ goes through the queue and but is also visible to moderators, IIRC. But I was incorrect about the dupe; it is the fact that the post is *already being reviewed* that hides the option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters by the way moderators recently asked SE team to [Hide “not an answer” and “very low quality” flags in the moderator flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243145/165773). As far as I know, one-hour delay in pushing such flags into mod queue is currently being tested at SO